# Probability of NOT getting a straight or flush

Tags: probability

What is the probability of NOT getting a straight or a flush in a 5 card poker game ?

I tried this

**i) Count all the straights and eliminate the straight flushes from it. This will give the number of (straights that are NOT a flush).**

Number of straights=10*(4^5)

Number of straight flushes = 10*4=40

So the number of straights that are NOT flush = 10*(4^5)-40=10200

**ii) Count all the flushes and eliminate the straight flushes from it. This will give the number of (flushes that are NOT straight).**

Number of flushes=4*C(13,5)

Number of straight flushes = 10*4=40

So the number of flushes that are NOT straight = 4*C(13,5)-40=5108

**iii) Count the straight flushes = 40**

**iv) Sum up i),ii) and iii) and subtract it from the total number of 5 card poker hands.**

C(52,5)-(10200+5108+40) = C(52,5)-15348 = 2583612

I thought that the value got in iv) over C(52,5) gives the probability

But it turns out that this is wrong. Right answer is at
https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120204031919AArcIOQ

My question is

Why is this procedure leading me to the wrong answer ??

i),ii) and iii) all are correct, yet how come i get a wrong answer here?

Comment: Let $A$ be the event of getting a straight, let $B$ be the event of getting a flush.  Then you are looking for $P[(A\cup B)^c]$, where $S^c$ denotes the complement of a set $S$.

Comment: Please avoid strings of capital letters.  They are akin to yelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done just fine.  The link you give is counting something different.  It demands that the five cards have different ranks.  Your count allows the hand AS,AH,AD,4C,5S.  The link does not.  Note that its count of total hands is about half of yours.

Comment: Are u saying that my answer is correct and the answer at the yahoo link is wrong ?  Are u sure ?  I am following the book 'Discrete Math and its applications' by Kenneth H Rosen, 7th edition. The book says that the answer in the yahoo link is correct.

Comment: No, I am saying that you are doing a different problem.  You did not demand that the cards have different ranks.  The yahoo link requires that the cards have different ranks.  That is the point of its count of hands being ${13 \choose 5}4^5=1317888$ while you have ${52 \choose 5}=2598960$ hands.  The yahoo answer has the same number of straights/flushes, but not the other hands.

Comment: Thanks Ross. Understood. The question in the book does specify the constraint of having 5 different kinds or ranks and also NOT being a flush or a straight. I missed that constraint. This question can be closed now.